# Как добавить каждому элементу меню в span его обратный индекс?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть к примеру такой код:

```
<li><a href="#1"><span></span>Lorem</a></li> 
<li><a href="#2"><span></span>Facere</a></li>
...
```

надо сделать вот так (то есть, добавить индекс по уменьшению):

```
<li><a href="#1"><span>#7</span>Lorem</a></li>
<li><a href="#2"><span>#6</span>Facere</a></li>
...
```

Как это реализовать с помощью jQuery? Каким методом?

Comment: Имхо такое лучше на сервере строить, так как сервер знает, сколько будет элементов в списке, а клиенту придется перечислять.

Comment: та да, дали задачку надо решить, поэтому ответ о сервере их не устроит:)))  а элементов 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу:

```
<li><a class="stack" href="#1"><span></span> qwe</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#2"><span></span> rwe</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#3"><span></span> wer</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#4"><span></span> sdf</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#5"><span></span> vxv</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#6"><span></span> bty</a></li>
<li><a class="stack" href="#7"><span></span> wer</a></li>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var revers = $('a.stack').get().reverse();
        $('a.stack').each(function(i,e){
            $(e).find('span').text( $(revers[i]).attr('href') );
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPD1**
Оптимизированный вариант:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $links = $('a.stack'),
            revers = $links.get().reverse()
            ;
        $links.each(function(i,e){
            $(e).find('span').text( $(revers[i]).attr('href') );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: не совсем так:))) надо span добавить индекс

Comment: У Вас просто с решеткой. Надо без?

Comment: надо вот так: <li><a href="#1"><span>#7</span>Lorem</a></li> то есть что бы индекс появился в спане

Comment: Вы мой код выполняли?

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Этот запрос оптимизирован по количеству обращений к DOM:

```
$(function() {
    var list = $('a.stack');
    var len = list.length-1;
    list.each(function(idx,elem) {
        var text = "#" + (len-idx+1);
        //var text = $(list[len-idx]).attr('href'); // или текст достаем из href           
        $(elem).find('span').text(text);
    });
});
```